# 503 service unavailable magento 2.4.3 update

Tags: error, upgrade, maintenance, magento2.4.3

Got a 503 service unavailale for https://takoda.shop/ , only it is not maintenance, because maintenance.flag is deleted and also disabled.

I did a new magento update yesterday, everything was basically working fine.

Today I check, and have this error, am doing it all, restart services, doing the setup update deploy, you name it...

Stays stuck in this, maybe it is because of magento 2.4.3 update, the htaccess issue, because it is now in pub

Anyone could have any clue?

Thank you

Comment: Analyse your log files (Magento and Web server) to try and determine what error is causing the web server to return the 503 error,

Comment: From what version of Magento? Could be some incompatibility or badly overwritten files from custom modules

Comment: Thank you, am checking logs, not seeing anything suspicous, from version 2.4 to 2.4.3

Comment: Have you checked your hosting service? You may have reached the limit of your resources (CPU, Memory, I/O). If you have CPanel, resources are shown on your right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in production mode, the errors which would otherwise be visible in developer mode will sometimes return a maintenance page in order to avoid revealing possibly sensitive data in the browser to the public.

I would debug this, or start debugging, by doing the following:

1. SSH into your server
2. From the root of your Magento project, run `tail -f var/log/*.log`. This will monitor all files with the .log extension in realtime.
3. In your browser, replicate the issue while monitoring the terminal where you ran step #2.

Comment: Thank you all so much, the limted resources, doesn't seem to be it, also have done your log monitoring, couldn't find anything right now, suspecting it has something to do with the new magento 2.4.3 pub index.php file, from pub folder now, that somehow somewhere the root document folder need to be changed to the pub folder, am not sure where to do this, am working on it